# Visual Studio 2013 and Nu get gets frozen wenn adding mvvmcross

Tags: visual-studio-2013, xamarin, nuget

first of all i work with Visual Studio 2013, Windows 7 and Xanmarin.

I started a new project a plc and after that i added a second project in the map; thats a Android project for my UI.
Then i also installed MVVMcross, but when i tried to Start it after the installment was finished, it froze after a few secound and the only thing i can do is to stop the entire process.
The last message is MVVMCROSSHotTuna.StarterPack3.1.1 is adding to [Androidapplication Name]
Does anyone have a solution for this or the same problems?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay i solved the Problem, i've only Update the Android SDK